# Jenkins: how save the logging outputs saved through Gradle testing into Jenkins Build History

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am working with:

- Jenkins 2.64
- Gradle 3.5
- Spring Framework 4.3.8

I am able to execute a Main java class through a Gradle task through Jenkins.
Therefore I can execute a **Job** N times to work around JMX and for each Job execution I have the `Build History` where I am able to see the logging outputs **from my business classes** *for each* interaction.

**Note** the history saves each logging outputs for each Job's execution

The problem is with testing.

Through Jenkins I am able to execute a Job related with a Gradle Test command, such as: `gradle test --tests`. Here two behaviors:

- Gradle saves the logging outputs **from my business classes** through its own output directory `build\reports\tests\test` (it is the expected, I am fine with this)
- Jenkins worked fine about the execute the `Gradle` test command **but** all the logging outputs are **only** posted through the Gradle Test reports but not in Jenkins, it in `Build History`.

Thus the `Jenkins` does not contain the logging outputs *from my business classes*. Therefore if I execute N times through my developing cycle the Test Job. I only am able to see the latest logging outputs **only** through the `Gradle Test Reports`, sadly `Jenkins` does not keep these logging outputs through `Build History`.

How resolve this? Some basic configuration or a plugin is need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to save junit reports in Jenkins, you can use [JUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin)

Individual reports are located at ***build/test-results/test/*.xml***

If you are using Declarative Pipelines you can use the following script

```
junit 'build/test-results/test/*.xml'
```

Since you are pointing to ***build\reports\tests\test\index.html*** which is the gradle test report, you can also save that report using [HTML Publisher Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin)

My suggestiong is to use JUnit Plugin for better integration.

Answer (score 2):

To save artifacts from your build you can use the [`archiveArtifacts`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#archive-build-output-artifacts) pipeline command

It would look something like:

`archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'build/reports/tests/test/*'`